# inner join error on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and i'm trying to do a inner join between some tables that I have.

The following code works:

```
select 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_compra, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_item, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_descricao, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_quantidade, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_valor, 
tb_fornecedores.nome_fornecedor
from tb_itens_pedido_compra, 
tb_pedido_compra 
inner join tb_fornecedores on tb_fornecedores.id_fornecedor = tb_pedido_compra.id_fornecedor
```

but when I try to do this:

```
select 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_compra, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_item, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_descricao, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_quantidade, 
tb_itens_pedido_compra.ip_valor, 
tb_fornecedores.nome_fornecedor,
tb_produto.nome_produto 
from tb_itens_pedido_compra, 
tb_pedido_compra 
inner join tb_fornecedores on tb_fornecedores.id_fornecedor = tb_pedido_compra.id_fornecedor
inner join tb_produto on tb_produto.id_produto = tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_produto;
```

the query results in this:

```
Mensagem 4104, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 12
O identificador de várias partes "tb_itens_pedido_compra.id_produto" não pôde ser    associado.
```

according to SQL Server documentation, this should be translated to this:

```
The multi-part identifier "%.*ls" could not be bound.
```

what can I do to make this work? am I using inner join wrong?

Comment: do you have column `id_produto` in table `tb_itens_pedido_compra`?

Comment: @RomanPekar yes http://i.imgur.com/V22OnYf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed at least one column to join, suggesting also use table aliases

```
from tb_itens_pedido_compra as ipc
    inner join tb_pedido_compra as pc on pc.id_compra = ipc.id_compra
    inner join tb_fornecedores as f on f.id_fornecedor = pc.id_fornecedor
    inner join tb_produto as p on p.id_produto = ipc.id_produto
```

Based on your schema this should work

Comment: nevermind, i forgot to replace the alias. it worked! thanks :)